# New to DJango need to fill form with initial data in get_data

Tags: python, django, forms, openstack

Here is my html:

```
{% block my_dashboard_main %}
<form action="status/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

My urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'status/$', views.status),
    url(r'thanks/$', views.thanks),
)
```

Here is my views.py:

```
STATUS_CHOICES = (
    ("GOOD", "Good"),
    ("BAD", "Bad"),
    ("COMPROMISED", "Compromised")
)

def thanks(request):
    return render(request, "my_dashboard/ssa_panel/sent.html')

class SsaForm(forms.Form):
    status = forms.ChoiceField(choices = STATUS_CHOICES, label="Status:")

def status(request):
    print("STATUS CALLED method=",request.method)
    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        form = SsaForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
        if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
            # Process the data in form.cleaned_data
            # ...
            print("redirect to THANKS!")
            return HttpResponseRedirect('thanks/') # Redirect after POST
    else:
        print("Requesting form\n")
        form = SsaForm(initial = {"status", "Good"}) # An unbound form

    return render(request, 'my_dashboard/ssa_panel/index.html', {
        'form': form,
    })

class IndexView(views.APIView):
    # A very simple class-based view...
    template_name = 'my_dashboard/ssa_panel/index.html'

    def get_data(self, request, context, *args, **kwargs):
        print("GET_DATA Called", context)
        # Add data to the context here...
       return context
```

The first time my page renders the I want the status to show up. It doesn't. Just the Submit button. After I submit once the "Status: [Good] <- combo box" is there. I want to go get the data for the for status in get_data and set it but I don't know how. do I set context['status']="Good" or something like that?

I'm obviously new to DJango and REST stuff.

Comment: It seems like you are originally rendering the template with the APIView, then submitting it to the `status` function-based view, which re-renders on error. I don't understand why you are doing that; you should just use the status for the original GET that renders the unsubmitted form.

Comment: Not sure I follow what you are saying.

Comment: I'm not sure how to get status called with a method="GET' to get to the else part and fill the form up. That else where I print "Requesting form" never is called. I figured I need to do it in the get_data for the APIView (This stuff is running in open stack)

Comment: I don't understand what the APIView is for at all. Your URL should go straight to the status view, where it would be a GET and therefore show the initial form. Just get rid of the APIView.

Comment: In the end what I'm trying to do is have this form that has a status prefilled via a API call and set. Then the data is put into the form. The user selected a status and hits submit and it posts. The secodn part works, but the form is blank becasue get_data is called and I do nothing there. I'm not sure what to do there on the page load to get the form temple to load up.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to construct your initial value dictionary incorrectly using a comma (,) instead of a colon *and* also using the wrong choice key. Instead of

```
form = SsaForm(initial = {"status", "Good"})
```

try

```
form = SsaForm(initial = {"status": "GOOD"})
```

Comment: Yeah I caught that. Still doesn't help me in what I'm supposed to do in the get_data function.